# How to manage customer calls?

Tags: custom-object

We have a requirement to provide functionality for user to manage customer calls. Does Salesforce provide an OOB feature for this? Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that by manage you mean track information about calls that have already occurred. By default Lead and Account Activity History have a button called "Log Call" which allow you to log information about calls for the given object.

To manage future calls you can use the activities tab to setup Tasks or Events to remind the user to make a call, and then Log A Call after said Task/Event occurs.

Comment: Since you're new to StackExchange, if this answered your question, then please click the green check image to the left of this answer.